# BAM and Tracking Profile Editor issue for different Activities of the same View

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-bam

I am facing a very strange issue with BAM and Tracking Profile Editor.
I have a View with 4 Activities in it. Everything was working fine. Off late, there was no data being tracked. I tried to resolve it by removing the tracking profile and applying it back again.

Now, only one activity's data is being tracked. Which ever Activity's TPE I enable at the last, that activity tracks the data, but the remaining one's stop tracking the data.

Comment: Usually no data is tracked if one of the ports you are tracking has been deleted or renamed.  You should get an error when you re-import the tracking profile that contains a port that does not exist.  What changes occurred just before the tracking stopped working?

Comment: There are no ports deleted or modified. Also, no errors after i re-import the tracking profile. The changes I did was just removed the tracking profile for each activity(separate btt file) and applied back again as i was not seeing data being tracked for one of the activities. Now no data is tracked for all the activities apart from the one which i apply lately.

Comment: I meant to say the one which i apply at the last